# How to re-use installed VSCode server when connecting to fresh docker instance?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, ssh

I'm running a docker image on a Linux server. The container mounts `/home/<USER>` from the underlying Linux machine so I have access to all my files.
On my local machine I connect from VSCode via SSH to the container to work on the project.

Upon the first connection VSCode installs a server into the remote `/home/<USER>/.vscode-server` and, of course, all remotely installed extensions go there as well.

I can close the connection and re-connect without problems.

But once the docker instance is shutdown and started again. VSCode seems to think it is a new remote machine and tries to install its server again failing with

```
> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/<USER>/.vscode-server/bin’Creating the se
> rver install dir failed...
> 2fe8b7d51fa4: start
> exitCode==34==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId====
> arch====
> tmpDir==/tmp==
> platform====
> unpackResult====
> : Permission denied
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
[10:44:20.231] > extInstallTime==== 
> serverStartTime====
> 2fe8b7d51fa4: end  
[10:44:20.231] Received install output: 
exitCode==34==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId====
arch====
tmpDir==/tmp==
platform====
unpackResult====
: Permission denied
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime==== 
serverStartTime====

[10:44:20.233] Resolver error: Error: Permission denied
```

The current workaround is - every time docker has been restarted for some reason - to delete ~/.vscode-server entirely, let VSCode install a fresh server and again select all the relevant extensions for remote installation.

Is there a way to tell VSCode to just use what is already there?

PS: yes, I have checked access rights to ~/.vscode-server, yes I changed user and group to my user account, even tried to chmod to 777. Does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. VSCode needs to connect to the workstation first, install the server and extensions and after that can be used in the Docker instances without the above problem.